# Arrays position inside foreach

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In here i wanted to check elements 0th position is settelg or not... is this correct?  messageIn comes from SMS gateway.In that message i wanted to check Array 0th position is setelg or not

```
public void ValidateReceivedMessage(string messageIn)
 {
    int MaleMooseID=1;
   //ArrayList msg_arr = new ArrayList();
   //string[] msg_arr = {messageIn};
   if (messageIn != null)
    {
       string[] msg_arr = messageIn.Split(' ');
       int size = msg_arr.Length;
       foreach (string _element in msg_arr)
       {
           if (_element == "settelg")
           {

            Response.Redirect("../DesktopModules/SMSFunction/SeenSMS.ascx?    value=1&arr=" + string.Join("|", msg_arr, 0, msg_arr.Length));

           }
           else if(_element =="skuttelg")
           {

           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: A `foreach` loops over *each* element of an `IEnumerable`, therefore your code checks every element of `msg_arr` for being equal to settelg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need foreach loop here.because you need only access the 0th element know just if condition enough for it.

```
if(msg_arr[0] == "setelg") { 
//Item found or true
 } 
else { 
//Item not found or false
 }
```

Don't use foreach here.It's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for this:

> i wanted to check Array 0th position is setelg or not

You don't need foreach for this, you can simply do:

```
if(msg_arr[0] == "settelg")
{
//found
}
else
{
//not found
}
```

or use [string.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) to compare the string with ignore case

Comment: Later i wanted to check the other elements also..then need foreach loop know?

Comment: @NimanthaPrasad, you need to rephrase your question, it not clear what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
if (msg_arr.Length > 0 && String.Equals(msg_arr[0],"settelg", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
    // ... Do something
}
```